# ElasticSearch Connection Timed Out in EC2 Instance

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I am setting up an ELK Stack (which consists of ElasticSearch, LogStash and Kibana) in a **single EC2 instance**.  AWS EC2 instance. I am following the documentation from the elastic.co site.

**TL;DR; I cannot access my ElasticSearch interface hosted in an EC2 from the Web URL. How to fix that?**

> Type : m4.large
> vCPU   : 2
> Memory : 8 GB
> Storage: 25 GB (EBS)

Note : I have provisioned the EC2 instance **inside a VPC** and **with an Elastic IP**.

I have installed all 3 components. ElasticSearch and LogStash are running as services while Kibana is running via the command `./bin/kibana` inside *kibana-7.10.1-linux-x86_64/* directory.

When I curl the ElasticSearch endpoint using

```
curl http://localhost:9200
```

I get this JSON output. (Which means the service is running and is accessible via Port 9200).

[image]

However, when I try to access the same URL via my browser, I get an error saying

> Connection Timed Out

[image]

Isn't this supposed to return the same JSON output as the one I've mentioned above?

I have attached the [elasticsearch.yml](https://gofile.io/d/2KqCKx) file here (Hosted in gofile.io).

Here are the Inbound Rules for the EC2 instance.

[image]

**EDIT** : I tried changing the `network.host: 'localhost'`
to `network.host: 0.0.0.0` and restarted the service but this time I got an error while starting the service. I attached the screenshot of that.
[image]

**EDIT 2** : I have uploaded the [updated elasticsearch.yml](https://gofile.io/d/h7y61m) to Gofile.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following line in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file:

```
node.name: node-1
network.host: 'localhost'
```

With that configuration, your ES cluster is only accessible from the same host and not from the outside. According to the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#common-network-settings), you need to either specify `0.0.0.0` or a specific publicly accessible IP address, otherwise that won't work.

Note that you also need to [configure the following two lines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-settings.html) in order for the cluster to properly form:

```
discovery.seed_hosts: ["node-1-ip-address"]

# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but setting 0.0.0.0 gave me an error, this time while starting the service. I edited the question and appended the relevant screenshot.

Comment: I will check this out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this and it fixed the service start issue. The service is running again. However, I still cannot connect to the 9200 port via Web URL.

Comment: Also,by node, you mean the same EC2 instance itself, right?

Comment: You need a public IP address in order to connect from the outside, i.e. not one starting with `10.x.y.z`

Comment: I am using an Elastic IP, which is in 13.x.y.z format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227013/discussion-between-sandun-and-val).